# jQuery Each not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, each

I have the following code to add some validation to a form within an `on click` function.

```
    $(this).parent().find('input[type=text]:required').each(function() {
        alert('each');
        if($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).css('border-color', '#df8f8f');
            required_missing = true;
        } else {
            $(this).css('border-color', '#eeece4');
        }
    });
```

An alert above this code works, but the alert within it does not appear in IE9. I have a sneaky suspicion that it may be the `:required` pseudo selector, is there an alternative for IE?

Comment: In html required="true"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$(this).parent().find('input[type=text][required]').each(function() {
```

or:

```
$(this).parent().find('input[type=text]').each(function() {
    if($(this).attr('required')) {
        alert('each');
        if($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).css('border-color', '#df8f8f');
            required_missing = true;
        } else {
            $(this).css('border-color', '#eeece4');
        }
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

IE9 doesn't support the required attribute. Suggest you do a check for < IE9 and replace with a css class check instead.